# What does Promisify do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, promise

I was following Stephen Grinder tutorial where he started using Promisify.

For that he gave very vague explanation saying that redis needs a callback function and he finds that very untidy + redis does not support promises in NodeJS

And afterwards he did something like this

```
     const redis = require('redis')
      const redisURL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379';
      const redisClient = redis.createClient(redisURL);
      const util = require('util')

      client.get = util.promisify(client.get)

      const cachedBlog = await client.get(req.user.id)
```

For some reason I found the explanation to be vague, Can someone please explain this in the most human way? like what does he mean and what we are doing?

Comment: _"Promises are a popular solution to some of the drawbacks of the callback-style async APIs dominant in node.js libraries. But it's awkward to write an node.js application using promises when all the libraries you want to use are callback-based. Hence Promisify. It converts callback-style APIs to use promises instead."_ - [Source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promisify)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Promisify is used when you want to convert a callback function into a promise based function. Nowadays, is used promises because let the developers to write more structured code. With callbacks you have a problem called *pyramid of doom* (http://callbackhell.com/). Where each function is called inside the other and the code starts to grow horizontally. With promises you can use *then* to call another function. Let me show you.

> Callback Example

```
 a (function (data1) {
  b (function (data2) {
    c (function (data3) {
      d (function (data4) {
        e (function (data5) {
          f (function (data6) {
            // The Egyptians would be jealous of this pyramid!
          })
        }  
      })
    })
  })
})
```

> Promise example

```
a(data1)
.then(return b(data2))
.then(return c(data3))
.then(return d(data4))
.then(return e(data5))
```

If you want I can post a better example but I think that this will help you