# how to break logic into a controller and a model in a node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, model-view-controller

I do not quite understand how to properly break the logic on the controllers and models in nodeJS when working with the backend application. Suppose I have an example

This code is in the model of my application, and logically I understand that the model is only responsible for choosing from the database, and the controller and everything else should be done by the controller, but I don’t quite understand how to do this and I tried to transfer part of the code to the controller and export it, but I did not succeed (Please, help, at least with this example! The main thing for me is to understand the principle of working with MVC in the node !!!

```
exports.currentPostPage = function(req, res){


db.query('SELECT * FROM `posts`', function (err, result) {
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    var post = result.filter(item => {return (item.id == req.params.id)? item: false})[0];
    if (post === undefined){
      res.render('pages/404');
    } else {
      res.render('pages/post-page', {postId: req.params.id, item: post});
    }

  });
};
```

Comment: Keep it simple, real simple.  A model gets data and returns it from the database. Period. A controller here would be the router & response tool.  Response to a get or post request, send content back to the client (or where ever...)   Its not perfect, but have you tried the express-generate hello world example?  try that and understand each and every line of code in there.  Should take 20 minute or so, time well spent on the MVC path.  What you have here is NO MVC, make code that will work. [Express Generator Example](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html)  (-hbs = pretty easy)

Comment: @zipzit I'm understand what that is not MVC - In my Server.js File I have `app.get('/post/:id', pageroutes.currentPostPage);` and next step, all of the logic I'm using in this file (model) but I'm understand what that is not perfect... I want to have example of code for more understanding, can u write it for me one time?

Comment: Read my edit. Express-Generator is the perfect sample tool for you. In clean temp directory,  `$ npm install express-generator` (local install is fine).  Then `$ express --view=hbs myapp `  Spend some time checking out the code.  You can see how everything works together. Note: there is no model in that example.  A model does nothing but return data from the database, either as an object, or an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you're on the right track.  There's a lot of different ways to do it depending on preferences, but one pattern I've seen pretty commonly is to use the callback as a way to integrate.  For example, let's say you have your model file:

```
exports.getPostById = (id, cb) => {
  db.query('SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE id=?', [id], function (err, result) {
    if (err){
      return cb(err); // or, alternatively, wrap this error in a custom error
    }
    // here, your logic is just returning whatever was returned
    return cb(null, result); 
  });
};
```

Note I also am letting the DB handling the ID lookup, as it's probably more efficient at doing so for larger data sets.  You didn't say what DB module you're using, but all the good ones have some way of doing parametrized queries, so use whatever works w/ your DB driver.

Anyway, the Model file therefore handles just the data interaction, the controller then handles the web interaction:

```
// postController.js
const model = require('../models/postModel.js'); // or whatever you named it
exports.populatePost = (req, res, next, id) => {
  model.getPostById(id, (err, post) => {
    if (err) return next(err); // centralized error handler
    req.post = post;
    next(); 
  });
}

export.getOnePost = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.post) {
    return res.render('pages/post-page', req.post);
  }
  // again, central error handling
  return next({ status: 404, message: 'Post not found' });
}
```

I have mentioned central error handling; I vastly prefer it to scattering error handling logic all over the place.  So I either make custom errors to represent stuff, or just do like above where I attach the status and message to an anonymous object.  Either will work for our purposes.  Then, in a middleware file you can have one or more handler, the simplest like this:

```
// middleware/errors.js
module.exports = (err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err); // log it
  if (err.status) {
    return res.status(err.status).render(`errors/${err.status}`, err.message);
  } 
  return res.status(500).render('errors/500', err.message);
}
```

Finally, in your routing setup you can do things like this:

```
const postController = require('../controllers/postController');
const errorHandler = require('../middleware/errors.js');
const postRouter = express.Router();

postRouter.param('postId', postController.populatePost);
postRouter.get('/:postId', postController.getOnePost);
// other methods and routes

app.use('/posts', postRouter)

// later

app.use(errorHandler);
```

As was pointed out in the comments, some folks prefer using the Promise syntax to callbacks.  I don't personally find them *that* much cleaner, unless you also use the async/await syntax.  As an example, if your db library supports promises, you can change the model code to look like so:

```
exports.getPostById = async (id, cb) => {
  // again, this assumes db.query returns a Promise
  return await db.query('SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE id=?', [id]);
}
```

Then your controller code would likewise need to change to handle that as well:

```
// postController.js
const model = require('../models/postModel.js'); // or whatever you named it
exports.populatePost = async (req, res, next, id) => {
  try {
    const post = await model.getPostById(id)
    req.post = post
    return next()
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err)
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer is very complete, the only thing it's missing is promises instead of callbacks because nowadays promises is the way to go, callbacks can lead to bad and ugly code like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53239200/what-does-promisify-do/53239441#53239441

Comment: @pedroSilva In my experience, promises can be just as ugly unless you're also using async/await. Given that the OP started their code sample without using Promises, I felt it was an unnecessary addition to the answer. That said, I will add a short async/await version when I'm not on my phone.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, your example is very complete and detailed and I also upvoted it too, I just wanted to add a little bit more information, and async/await rocks man :D